# Problem with display of date in a html/thymeleaf edit form

Tags: java, spring, date, thymeleaf, dto

I have this little problem, that bothers me very much.

I am working on a blog, that runs it's backend in java (spring), whereas frontend is in html/css/thymeleaf.

I am working on displaying of user's profile and it's editing.

On my page, if you click on "edit profile", you will be redirected to form with valueas as firstName, lastName, etc. and finally birthday.
In that edit form, you should not see blank rows, but you should see filled in all the data from your profile, that are in database, and you can edit them.

And it is working, only the birthday is not shown! The value of birthday is blank in the form, despite it's saved in DB.

My thymeleaf form is like that:

```
<form class="d-flex flex-column gap-2" method="post"
                  th:action="@{'/profile/edit/' + ${profileId}}" th:object="${profileDTO}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstName" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                    <input id="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}" class="form-control" />
                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
                           th:errors="*{firstName}"></small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lastName" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" class="form-control" />
                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}"
                           th:errors="*{lastName}"></small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="birthday" class="control-label">Birthday</label>
                    <input type="date" id="birthday" th:value="*{birthday}" th:field="*{birthday}" class="form-control" />
                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('birthday')}"
                           th:errors="*{birthday}"></small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="interests" class="control-label">Interests</label>
                    <input id="interests" th:field="*{interests}" class="form-control" />
                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('interests')}"
                           th:errors="*{interests}"></small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="aboutMe" class="control-label">About Me</label>
                    <textarea id="aboutMe" class="form-control" th:field="*{aboutMe}"></textarea>
                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('aboutMe')}"
                           th:errors="*{aboutMe}"></small>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="clanky-tlacitko">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I tried to modify code in many ways.
If i change this:

```
<input type="date" id="birthday" th:value="*{birthday}" th:field="*{birthday}" class="form-control" />
```

To this:

```
<input type="date" id="birthday" th:value="*{birthday}" class="form-control" />
```

(which means if I get rid of parameter th:field)
It's magically working! The birthday is shown properly, when I click on "edit form". But on the other hand, because I got rid of th:field, after saving the form, birthday is not sent to server, so you actually cannot change it.

I know for sure, that the problem is not with my DTO. DTO is filled properly from DB, otherwise you would not see it in that last example.

There must be some problem with that thymeleaf form or something.
But I ran out of ideas.

Any ideas?
Thank you very much.

I tried many things:

```
<input type="text" id="birthday" th:value="${#temporals.format(profileDTO.birthday, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}" class="form-control datepicker" />
```

Which lead to the fact, the new values were not sent to server.

```
 <input type="date" id="birthday" th:value="*{birthday}" th:field="*{birthday}" class="form-control" />
```

In this case, the new data is sent to server, but you don't see the pre-filled value in the form, when you go to edit.

```
<input type="date" id="birthday" th:field="*{birthday}" class="form-control" />
```

The same.

```
<input type="date" id="birthday" th:value="*{birthday}" class="form-control" />
```

In this case, when you go to "edit profile", you see the value of birthday in the form, but you don't send a new value to the server.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

```
<input name="birthday" id="birthday" type="date" th:value="*{birthday}" class="form-control"/>
```

The property name matters!
I didn't know that.

I got rid of th:field and let there only th:value, added name and it is magically working.

Comment: With Thymeleaf you should not set `name`, `id` or `value` yourself. `th:field` will set all of those correctly for you. If you need to reference an `id` (for example "`for`" a `label`) use the [#ids](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#ids) helper functions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).